# Spring Batch Connection Pool issue Already in use

Tags: spring-batch, database-connection, spring-batch-tasklet, connection-pool, spring-batch-job-monitoring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoBCI.png)`when I am running the spring batch for saving the 15 csv file data into oracle database. it is saving 10 csv apart from that remaining csv file data are not saved it is throwing exception:-`

Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: All connections in the Universal Connection Pool are in use - [ 10, 10, 11, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9 ]"